# How do convert the following array into a hash?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
(3.years.ago.to_date..Date.today).map { |date| [date.month, date.year] }.uniq!
```

Returns:

```
[[11, 2008], [12, 2008], [1, 2009], [2, 2009], [3, 2009], [4, 2009], [5, 2009], [6, 2009], [7, 2009], [8, 2009], [9, 2009], [10, 2009], [11, 2009], [12, 2009], [1, 2010], [2, 2010], [3, 2010], [4, 2010], [5, 2010], [6, 2010], [7, 2010], [8, 2010], [9, 2010], [10, 2010], [11, 2010], [12, 2010], [1, 2011], [2, 2011], [3, 2011], [4, 2011], [5, 2011], [6, 2011], [7, 2011], [8, 2011], [9, 2011], [10, 2011], [11, 2011]]
```

How do I turn this into a Hash with this structure:

```
[
  [month => 11, year => 2008], 
  [month => 12, year => 2008], 
  [month => 1, year => 2009],
  etc
]
```

So I can use it like:

```
foo.first.month # returns 11
foo.first.year # returns 2008
```

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(3.years.ago.to_date..Date.today).map {|date| {:month => date.month, :year => date.year}}
=> [{:month=>11, :year=>2008}, {:month=>11, :year=>2008}, {:month=>11, :year=>2008}...]
```

The problem with this, however, is that you won't get the methods for free.  You'll have to override `method_missing` on Hash to give you the keys as methods.

```
class Hash
  def method_missing(method_name, *args)
    if key?(method_name)
      self[method_name]
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: foo.first returns `{:month=>11, :year=>2008}` but foo.first.months returns `NoMethodError: undefined method `month' for {:month=>11, :year=>2008}:Hash`. Any ideas why?

Comment: I see. To avoid this problem. Is it common to use an associative array instead. Is this sensible? Or is there a better way to do this with a hash approach?

Comment: Well, instead of `foo.first.month`, you could just do `foo.first[:month]`.

Comment: For my understanding. In Rails I am able to do things like `foo.first.month` when dealing with hashes. Why does one need to override the `method_missing` on Hash. Shouldn't it work automatically?

Comment: Because Rails does that for you already.  It's doing the same thing to have that effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'openstruct'
array = (3.years.ago.to_date..Date.today).map { |date| [date.month, date.year] }.uniq
array.map {|ary| OpenStruct.new([:month, :year].zip(ary))}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question needs work as your expected results don't make sense:

You don't have hash, you have an array of arrays... with key value pairs (you access arrays by index, not by key). But the keys are references to month and year objects that don't exist (I assume you wanted to make them strings or symbols). Then you also want to access them like objects instead of hashes (ie `array.first.month` vs `array.first[:month]`).

But anyway, you don't need to do anything special with these since date objects already present the month and year methods. You just need to pass a block to `uniq` to tell it what criteria you are using:

```
(3.years.ago.to_date..Date.today).to_a.uniq { |date| [date.month, date.year] }
```